# Sum of digits of 2-digit number is 9. If we switch places of digits, we obtain the number whose ratio to the first number is 8:5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sum of digits of 2-digit number is 9. The ratio of the number to the number with the digits switched is 8:5. What is the number?

My try:

We have number $10x+y$

Sum of digits: $x+y=9 \implies x=9-y$

We switch places of digits of first number and we win this relation:
$$(10y+x):(10x+y)=8:5 $$
$$(9y+9):(90-9y)=8:5 $$
$$ 117y=675 $$
What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What do "we win the number [...]", "we win this relation [...]" mean?

Comment: Oh man, I'm sorry, English is not my native language (obviously). I thought I was being clear! I don't know how to translate it differently.

Comment: The only two digit multiple of $9$ which is divisible by $5$ is $45$ and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Your problem simply has no solution. The only candidates for the original number are

$$54, 63,72,81, 90$$

(the second digit must be smaller, since otherwise, the ratio between the number and its "reverse" cannot be $8:5$),

and none of these numbers satisfies the second requirement:

$$54:45 = 6:5\\
63:36 = 7:4\\
72:27 = 8:3\\
81:18=9:2\\
90:09 = 10:1$$